# katacoda command not found

Tags: linux, bash, npm, katacoda

I'm trying to install the katacoda client. I used NPM to install it:

```
npm install -g katacoda-cli
```

The installation was successful but when I'm trying to run the `katacoda help` I've got the following error: `command not found: katacoda`. NPM installed katacoda here: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli`. If I run the following: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli/bin/run help` katacoda is executed correctly. I guess my problem is coming from my `$PATH`, which is set like this: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Comment: You have to have katacoda in your `$PATH`. You can soft link `/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli/bin/run` as `katacoda` somewhere in your `$PATH`

Comment: Thanks @PanwenWang how can I do that? I tried `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli/bin/run"`

Comment: You can go to one of the directories, say `/usr/local/bin`, and then run `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli/bin/run katacoda`. Then you should be able to run `katacoda` directly. If you don't have permissions to do so in `/usr/local/bin`, choose another directory where you have permissions, do the same and add the directory to your `$PATH`

Comment: Perfect that solved my problem. Can you add it as an answer and I will close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to one of the directories, say `/usr/local/bin`, and then run `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/lib/node_modules/katacoda-cli/bin/run katacoda`. Then you should be able to run `katacoda` directly. If you don't have permissions to do so in `/usr/local/bin`, choose another directory where you have permissions, do the same and add the directory to your `$PATH`